# Get the silverlight player into fullscreen mode from outside the silverlight code

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a silverlight mediaElement embeded in my asp.net page as follow:

```
<object id="SilverlightPlayer" data="data:application/x-silverlight," 
         type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="753" height="468" >
         <param name="source" value="ClientBin/VideoPlayer.xap"/>  
         <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
         <param name="OnResize" value="HandleResize" />
         <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
         <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
         <param name="windowless" value="true" />
         <param name="background" value="transparent" />
         <param name="initParams" id="SLInitParameters" />                    
</object>
```

I am implementing all the player controls from the asp.net side and invoking the SL methods using the javascript bridge. Everything works fine except the ability to put the silverlight player in full screen mode. `content.IsFullScreen = True;`

I have tried calling a method from javascript:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public void mediaFullScreen()
{
    var content = Application.Current.Host.Content;
    content.IsFullScreen = !content.IsFullScreen;
}
```

I put a button in the Silverlight code which works fine. So, I had the javascript call a the function above. I then changed the code invoke the click event on the SL full screen button, however, that does not work either:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer((Button)this.fullScreenButton);
IInvokeProvider ip = (IInvokeProvider)peer;
ip.Invoke();
```

I even wired up an event handler in the SL code to process the click event on the  tag:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = HtmlPage.Document; 
HtmlElement htmlEle = htmlDoc.GetElementById("buttonFullScreen");
htmlEle.AttachEvent("onclick", new EventHandler(this.OnConvertClicked));
```

Is there anyway I can get the SL to go into full screen mode from my  tag in the asp.net code?
(Using VS2010 and SL4)

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I found someone having the same problem and it says it can't be done from javascript because of security (see the comments): http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/02/06/Sharing-some-Silverlights-bits-Full-Screen-Mode-cannot-be-changed.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [full screen support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) documentation:

> A Silverlight-based application can enter full-screen mode only in
>   response to a user-initiated action.

and:

> Limiting the actions that enable full-screen mode ensures that the user is always the initiator of full-screen mode behavior.

This is the case also for other things, eg launching an open file dialog.

If you need to initiate from JavaScript you may have to turn to another approach from the Silverlight full-screen mode, ie maximizing it within the browser.

Comment: I saw that as well. I would think the `ip.Invoke();` would get around this because it is clicking the button from within the SL code.

Comment: I think you'd need to look into Microsoft's code to know how they detect "user-initiated action", as it seems you basically need to defeat it. If you could do that so easily isn't the "security" aspect of this restriction nonexistant?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, how it detects a user-initiated action. I guess if I want to use the full-screen mode I will need to keep a button in my SL code. Or, more likely, I will have to do my own full-screen mode. Sigh!

Comment: Given the restrictions of SL full screen (eg no keyboard, various other things) you might want to do that anyway. In Silverlight 5 trusted in-browser applications shouldn't have a restriction on user-initiated actions (little comfort to you I'm sure).